# Angular - enforcing a model format in a returned JSON array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

While using Angular I have the following model:

```
export interface MyModel {
    id: number;
    content: string;
}
```

In a service I make a request for JSON data that has the attributes of MyModel. Something like this:

```
function getMyModel() {
    return this.http
       .post('http://www.somewhere.com/getOneModel')
       .map(result => <MyModel> result.json())
       .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The returned JSON is something like this:

```
{ id: 1, content: "Stuff" }
```

In `getMyModel()` you'll see that while I `map()` the results I make sure that the JSON conforms to MyModel by doing this: `<MyModel> result.json()`.

Everything is working fine to this point.

Now I want to return an array of models and confirm all of them conform to MyModel.

```
function getLotsOfModels() {
    return this.http
       .post('http://www.somewhere.com/getLotsOfModels')
       .map(result => result.json())
       .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The returned JSON is something like this:

```
{[
    { id: 1, content: "Stuff" },
    { id: 2, content: "More stuff" }
]}
```

In this case `map()` cannot confirm the JSON array elements agree with MyModel since the result is an array. How can I check that the results are correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast them to `MyModel[]`.

```
function getLotsOfModels() {
    return this.http
     .post('http://www.somewhere.com/getLotsOfModels')
     .map(result => <MyModel[]> result.json())
     .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Typescript won't do any structural check, so casting this can only fail at runtime. If you have any methods on `MyModel`. The Json won't have them, and you'll run into problems, when you want to evoke a method.

For example, after you've obtained your model:

```
myModel.myMethod();
```

This will throw an error at runtime, since the underlying JSON, doesn't have the function defined and the compiler can't catch it because of the cast.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Array`/`List` there, to indicate it as a collection.

```
.map(result => Array<MyModel> result.json())
```